# Flutter and containers

Tags: flutter

Can someone explain to me why, even if I set the size of the root container, the container is still presented fullscreen, totally ignoring the with and height settings:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container( // grey box
      child: new Stack(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        children: [
          new Positioned( // red box
            child:  new Container(
              child: new Text(
                "Lorem ipsum",
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
              ),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red[400],
              ),
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            ),
            left: 24.0,
            top: 24.0,
          ),
        ],

      ), 
      width: 300.0,
      height: 200.0,
      color: Colors.grey[300],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are showing this widget directly without any parent widgets, you are not telling Flutter which view should be rendered above/outside the container in the hierarchy?

For example, try to add a `Scaffold` parent to your `Container` and it should solve your issue

```
return new Scaffold(

        body: new Container(
          width: 300.0,
          height: 200.0,
    ........
```